# Графика в Delphi. Как рисовать тень

Tags: delphi

Не понимаю, как нарисовать тень к фигуре, получается только заполнить ее.. 
Создаем пустой прямоугольник:

```
procedure TRct.draw;
begin
 with Form2.Image1.Canvas dо
  begin
   Brush.Color:=clWhite;
   FillRect(Form2.Image1.Canvas.ClipRect);
  end;
  Form2.Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
end;
```

А как его можно затенить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Brush.Style := bsSolid;
```

---

Если вы хотите что-то в духе "Canvas.DrawShadow(...)", то штатно в VCL такого нет. 
Однако, вы можете воспользоваться такой чудесной вещью как [GDI+](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml). Эта графическая библиотека умеет делать много интересного, включая размытие, прозрачность и градиенты, из которых вы сможете соорудить вполне приличную тень.

Comment: Это далеекоооо не даст желаемого эффекта....

Comment: может быть. я, если честно, не понимаю до конца, чего хочет добиться ТС. Я так понял что нужно затенить (shade) сам прямоугольник, чтобы он не был прозрачным.
Если же нужно, чтобы прямоугольник отбрасывал тень, нарисуйте прямоугольную тень, а сверху прямоугольник.

Comment: собственно, я и рисую прямоугольник за прямоугольником серого цвета, но хотелось бы все таки узнать, есть ли еще решение какое нибудь...

Comment: Обновил ответ.